# I am getting a size error when working with keras cifar10 dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I was making a little project on colabs using mnist. I then decided to change datasets when i got this vexing error. I made a post about this a while ago too. But it wasn't resolved.
Tell me where i went wrong.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

```
data = keras.datasets.cifar10
```

```
df = data.load_data()
```

```
(X_train, y_train),(X_test, y_test) = df
```

```
X_train_flat = X_train.reshape(-1,32*32)
X_test_flat = X_test.reshape(-1, 32*32)
```

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

```
model = Sequential([
                    #first hidden layer
                    Dense(units=10,
                          input_shape = (1024,),
                          activation='sigmoid'),
                    #second hidden layer
                    #Dense(units=10,
                     #     input_shape = (784,),
                      #    activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

```
model.fit(X_test_flat, y_train, epochs=15)#im getting the error on this line
```

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_flat)
```

```
model.evaluate(X_test_flat, y_test)
```

And the error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-5508f48e747b> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_test_flat, y_train, epochs=15)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1653                            for i in tf.nest.flatten(single_data)))
   1654     msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1655     raise ValueError(msg)
   1656 
   1657 

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 30000
  y sizes: 50000
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

Apologies for any formatting issues.  Im not on my pc rn

Comment: Look at here: X_test_flat, y_train, you are passing test X and Y train, which of course will not work.

Comment: You just have to pass X_train_flat instead of X_test_flat

Comment: @AnuragReddy I did try that
its giving the same error
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 150000
  y sizes: 50000
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Comment: CIFAR is color images, 32*32*3.

Answer (score 0):

Dataset reshaping is causing the error which you can achieve by using `Flatten layer` inside the model definition.

You can simply remove this line:

```
X_train_flat = X_train.reshape(-1,32*32)
X_test_flat = X_test.reshape(-1, 32*32)
```

and can define the flatten layer with dataset input shape in the  model definition as below:

```
model = Sequential([Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
                    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
                    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
                    Dense(10,activation='softmax'),
                    ])
```

Now, replace `X_test_flat` with `X_train` and `X_test_flat` with `X_test` for model training, evaluation and prediction.

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=15)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

Please have a look at the similar classification model [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification).